# If else statement with two conditions

Tags: php

Is it possible to have an if esle statement with two conditions?,

I have this code...

```
 if ($current_page == 1)
```

however could i write it so it was something like this

```
 if ($total_pages ==1 $current_page < $total_pages)
```

Have tried to write this several ways myself, but can not seem to get it to work.

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Code

```
 echo "$current_page"; echo "$total_pages";

     if ($current_page >= 1 && ($current_page < $total_pages)) { echo "next button should be here"; } else {echo "Nothing"; }
```

please see link below, you can see that it is page 1 of 4 and it gets to the nothing section.  when it should show next button here.

http://www.qrrw.net/k

Php Code

```
 $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
  $engine = $_GET['engine'];
  $manid = $_GET['manid'];
  $mgid = $_GET['mgid'];
  $file = 'http://mywebsite.com/page.xml?apikey=****&vid=****&limit=10&mgid='. $mgid.'&engine='. $engine.'&manid='.$manid.'&page=' . $pageNum;

  if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
   exit('Failed to open '.$file);

  $total_pages = $xml->results->attributes()->totalPages;
  $current_page = $xml->results->attributes()->currentPage;
  $total_results = $xml->results->attributes()->totalResults;

  $count = 0;
  $max = 2;
  foreach($xml->year as $year){ 

  $count++;
  echo '<td class="manu">'. "<a href='exact.php?manid=".$manid."&engine=".$engine."&mgid=".$mgid."&year=".$year['name']."'>".$year['name']."</a>";'   </td>';

 if($count >= $max){

 $count = 0;

 echo '</tr><tr>';
 }
 }
 $pageNum = $current_page = $xml->results->attributes()->currentPage;

 if ($current_page == 1) { } else {
    echo "<a href='years.php?page=".($pageNum - 1)."&engine=".($engine)."&manid=".($manid)."&mgid=".($mgid)."'><img src='../images/previous.fw.png' width='130' height='92' /></a>";
    }

    echo "$current_page"; echo "$total_pages";

    if ($current_page >= 1 && ($current_page < $total_pages)) { 
    echo "next button should be here"; 
    } else {
    echo "Nothing";
```

Comment: The logic here is unclear. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: ``total_pages`` cannnot be greater than a boolean value

Comment: @StanWilliams The logic you posted looks completely fine. See http://codepad.org/KnslsWjL

Comment: Hi, thanks, your example in code pad shows current page 4 and total pages 4 which should show nothing, but the link above shows current page 1 and total page 4

Comment: If you modify the code in the link I posted to have the current page being 1 you'll see that the "next button" comes up. (http://codepad.org/MFq76u85) This proves that the logic is fine - so there must be some other problem in your code. Please post your **entire** php file.

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket after the last else, which could be why it always prints "Nothing". Although it should be giving you an error...

Comment: Sorry that was just where i copied the php code from the page and missed it, so i didn't have to post the html

Comment: Please add `var_dump($current_page); var_dump($total_pages);` to your code after the last else and post the results.

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: I will post a new answer. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13312378/1324019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that if statement is failing is because it expects both `$current_page` and `$total_pages` to be integers, yet they are not.

As you can see from the results of `var_dump` that you posted, both of those variables contain objects complex enough that they cannot be implicitly converted to integers.

Try adding the following code before the if statement:

```
$current_page = (int)$current_page[0];
$total_pages = (int)$total_pages[0];
```

By this point your question really has nothing to do with what you originally asked...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what logic you're trying to accomplish here, but you can test two conditions this way:

```
 // if total pages are equal to 1 or 1 is less than total pages     
 if (($total_pages == 1) || (1 < $total_pages))
```

See [php logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

If you're looking to compare that the current page is less than the number of total pages and the current page is greater than one as per your edit, you could do:

```
if ($current_page > 1 && ($current_page < $total_pages))
```

Or if you'd just like to check that total_pages is greater than or equal to one, you can do:

```
if ($total_pages >= 1)
```

Comment: Why not just `$total_pages >= 1`?

Comment: @Vulcan That would make much more sense in this scenario. But he did ask specifically about testing two conditions.

Comment: True, but your current example is a bit misleading in that sense.  OP appears to be looking for the usage of `>=`, so it'd be a good bit of information to include in your answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, i just added an update actually, i don't know where my head is to day, but yes  i guess it should be if total pages > 1 and current_page is less than the total pages.  basically i am trying to hide and show a next button depending on resutls

Comment: @StanWilliams I think the second code snippet in my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: me too, but it doesn't want to work, i did make an error it should have been if current page is greater than 1 and if the current page is less than  the total pages, it shows that i have two pages total but on the second page it still shows a button when it shouldn't

Comment: @StanWilliams Post more code. I doubt the problem is solely with the if statement at this point. I edited my answer again at any rate.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually have as many [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) separated by [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) as you want.

```
<?php 
    if(($value [Comparison Operator] $value) [Logical Operator] ($value [Comparison Operator] $value)){
      //do something
    }
?>
```

### Comparison Operators

```
$a == $b     Equal
$a === $b  Identical
$a != $b     Not equal
$a <> $b     Not equal.
$a !== $b  Not identical
$a < $b      Less than
$a > $b      Greater than
$a <= $b     Less than or equal to
$a >= $b     Greater than or equal to
```

### Logical Operators

```
$a and $b  And 
$a or $b     Or
$a xor $b  Xor
! $a       Not
$a && $b   And 
$a || $b   Or
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both of conditions met you use **AND &&**

```
if(($b > $a) && ($d > $f)
```

For either one of them matching use **OR ||**

```
if(($b > $a) || ($d > $f)
```

For the full reference see : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php